# Javascript Reduce assign and return with implicit return

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to remove the keys from my object where the value is equal to `null`.

I made use of the `filter` function on `Object.entries` combined with a reducer.

I managed to create this snippet, but it has a breach: If any key contains a falsey value, the reducer will return the wrong value:

```js
const obj = {
  boolKey: true,
  intKey: 1,
  nullKey: null,
  falseyKey: 0,
  stringKey: 'string',
};

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
  .reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => (accumulator[key] = value) && accumulator, {});

console.log(result); // 0
```

But with this object the result is as expected:

```js
const obj = {
  boolKey: true,
  intKey: 1,
  nullKey: null,
  stringKey: 'string',
};

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
  .reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => (accumulator[key] = value) && accumulator, {});

console.log(result);

// { boolKey: true, intKey: 1, stringKey: 'string' }
```

I know there are other ways to achieve this, but I'd like to know how to make use of the implicit return in the reducer safely.

Comment: *I know there are other ways to achieve this* ... not only *other* but also *better*. What's your usecase to not use an explicit `return` ?

Comment: What I meant by *other* was deleting the keys without filtering the array and performing other actions. I could reuse that kind of mechanism by passing a predicate with a more complex logic for example, but this is just a simple example just for the post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your callback function is not returning an object as the accumulator each time it is called. You only return an object when the `value` you assign is truthy and the current accumulator is an object. For example, when `value` is 0,  `value`  is falsy, so the `accumilator[key] = value` will return `0`. Since the LHS of the `&&` operator is falsy, it will short-circuit, resulting in the falsy value of `0` being returned. One way you could fix this is by using the comma-operator:

```js
const obj = { boolKey: true, intKey: 1, nullKey: null, falseyKey: 0, stringKey: 'string', };

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
  .reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => (accumulator[key] = value, accumulator), {});

console.log(result);
```

Or by reducing to an object by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const obj = { boolKey: true, intKey: 1, nullKey: null, falseyKey: 0, stringKey: 'string', };

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [key]: value}), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I really like the example with the spread syntax ! And thanks for the comma separator, I didn't know that.

Comment: @nook no worries. I like adiga's .fromEntries approach as well if you can support it. If you need better browser support reduce is probably the next option ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const obj = {
  boolKey: true,
  intKey: 1,
  nullKey: null,
  stringKey: 'string',
};

const result = Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: value }), {});

console.log(result);
```

OR

the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to assign a value and return the accumulator

```
.reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => (accumulator[key] = value,  accumulator), {})
```

OR

You could also use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create an object from the filtered entries

```js
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([, value]) => value !== null)
)
```

Comment: We forget too much `Object.fromEntries()` ! This is not a method I was expecting since I'm using ES6, but it's good to know. Nick Parsons proposed a nice solution with the spread operator, but that's a nice workaround.